# Adding a background task to Django

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-rest-framework, twitterapi-python

I don't know if I've chosen a good approach here. In fact, there's a very high chance that I'm completely wrong about this.

In my Django Application, I need to establish a connection with Twitter API, to continuously get desired tweets. In order to do so, I've written a script using

```
def connect():
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream",
        headers=headers,
        stream=True,
    )
    for response_line in response.iter_lines():
        if response_line:
            json_response = json.loads(response_line)
            print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The problem is, I don't know how and where to call this function in Django.
Here's what I've found so far:

- This function blocks the flow of its caller, So it needs to be
  executed concurrently, whether as a process or a thread.
- In order to execute such a function, also known as a background task,
  I need to either use heavy complex options, such as **Celery**,    or
  light-weight libraries such as **DjangoBackgroundTasks**.
- Obviously, I went with DjangoBackgroundTasks and installed it. But now there are a few problems that I can't solve. **Firstly, where in the code should I call my connect() function?** I've seen people call this in console, but that's not what I want to do, I need to call this, and execute it besides the main Django app.

P.S I've seen such implementations as the link below, but honestly, they are out of my level, and I can't figure how the code works.
https://github.com/michaelbrooks/django-twitter-stream/tree/master/twitter_stream

Comment: my first idea: create separated script which gets tweets and it saves in file or database - and run it manually/separatelly. On Linux you could use `cron` to run it periodically (every few minutes). And Django run separatelly and read tweets from this file or database. Django and this script may run separatelly and they don't have to start from one script.